# How can I find all the files on my Mac that have any named forks?

Tags: filesystem, file, hfs+

How can I, from either the command line, any of the included tools, or some third-party tool, go through all the files on my Mac and list any that use "named forks".

Such files should be very rare but I'm interested in this now-deprecated feature of the OS. Files with resource forks might still be around, but I'm interested in files that have other forks besides the main/data fork and the resource fork.